# Is it good practice to update a post referencing an outdated book edition?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I was looking at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456518/5198805

and noticed they were referencing Effective Java 2nd Edition..... On my desk I had the 3rd edition and noticed the referenced chapter 26 had changed places and was now chapter 23 in 3rd edition...... Would it be good to edit the answer and update the Edition/Section being referenced? Or perhaps add in a second line stating the 3rd edition location so the answer provides both 2nd and 3rd edition?

I could see this becoming cumbersome once a book starts issuing out 10+ editions etc..

Comment: Personally, I would just edit the references out. There's no reason for them to be in there except as appeals to authority, and if you're answering, you have the authority. It's a nice-to-have, not vital to the answer. I'd get more answers first though; I'm not an authority ;).

Comment: The answer is from 2010.  Did the 3rd edition exist in 2010?

Comment: I think answers should be seen in context of the time to some degree. If it makes sense to update the reference and the update won't essentially change what the reference was *refering* to semantically, it's okay. But this could cause much work to verify. For practical reasons, I'd suggest you to just keep it as it is most of the time, except when it's "screaming" for an update.

Comment: Does the 3rd edition bring any revisions to the *content* of that chapter? If so, then it's probably a good idea - if there was a problem with the information in the 2nd edition and the 3rd edition fixed it, then seems like an improvement to update it. If the content is the same but just changed places...does it really matter? I'm sure people who are interested in looking up the information in the book would be able to find the content in whichever edition they have.